# Homomorphisms of modules over a corner ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, homological-algebra, idempotents

Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring and suppose that we can write $1 = e_1 + e_2 + \dots + e_n$ where the $e_i$ are pairwise orthogonal idempotents. Let $S = e_1 S e_1$, and consider the right $S$-modules $e_iRe_1$. Then we have $e_jRe_i \subset \text{Hom}_S(e_iRe_1,e_jRe_1)$ where $e_iRe_j$ gives rise to morphisms by left multiplication. Is it necessarily the case that this inclusion is actually an inequality, and if not, are there any general conditions under which it is an equality?

Edit: It seems that $\text{Hom}_S(e_i R e_1, e_j R e_1) \cong \text{Hom}_R(e_iRe_1 \otimes_S e_1R, e_jR)$ and that $\text{Hom}_R(e_iR,e_jR) = e_jRe_i$ so it suffices to show that $e_iRe_1 \otimes_S e_1R \cong e_i R$. This seems plausible, perhaps if there's some domain-like condition on $R$ or $S$.

Second edit: I suppose it might be useful if I included the specific case of interest to me. Let $R$ be the path algebra of a finite quiver $Q$ with vertices labelled by $\{1, \dots , n\}$, let the $e_i$ be the vertex idempotents, and set $S = e_1Re_1$. In this setting, is the claim true?

Comment: It follows from you edit that you want $Re_1\otimes_{S} e_1 R \cong R$ as bimodule.  But $Re_1 \otimes_S e_1 R \to Re_1 R$ given by the multiplication $re_1\otimes e_1 r' \mapsto re_1 r'$ is a surjective $R$-$R$-bimodule map, which embeds strictly into $R$.  In case $e_1 = 1_R$, then you need also $(Re_1 R)$ to be projective as left $R$-module and projective as right $R$-module in order to have bimodule isomorphism.

Comment: Another dual way to look at this is to use the other pair $(-\otimes_R Re_1, Hom_S(Re_1,-))$ of adjunction (you are using the adjunction $(-\otimes_S e_1 R , Hom_R(e_1R , -))$, and $Hom_R(e_1 R,-)\cong \otimes_R Re_1$).  Then you obtain the condition which require you have to have $Hom_S(Re_1,e_j R)\cong e_j R$, which is only possible if $Re_1 \cong S = e_1 Re_1$.

Comment: @Aaron: Thanks for those comments. I updated the question to give a specific example; do you know if it is true in that case?